# n-queen greedy algorithm python

Tags: python, greedy

Here is the code for a greedy queens on a chess table and I don't understand how it works:

//here create the table

```
def create_table(m,n):
t=[]
one_line=[]
for i in range(0,m):
    one_line.append(0)
for i in range(0,n):
    t.append(one_line)
return t
```

//here I ve lost in this loops. What's the purpose of cost and how to understand easily what's in here?

```
def getPositionCost(t,pi,pj):

n=len(t)
m=len(t[0])
cost=0
for i in range(0,len(t)):
    for j in range(0,len(t[i])): 
        if pi==i and t[i][j]==0:
            cost=cost+1
        if pj==j and t[i][j]==0:
            cost=cost+1
i=pi
j=pj
while i>0 and j>0:
    i=i-1
    j=j-1
    if t[i][j]==0:
        cost=cost+1
i=pi
j=pj
while i<n-1 and j<m-1:
    i=i+1
    j=j+1
    if t[i][j]==0:
        cost=cost+1
i=pi
j=pj
while i>0 and j<m-1:
    i=i-1
    j=j+1
    if t[i][j]==0:
        cost=cost+1
i=pi
j=pj
while i<n-1 and j>0:
    i=i+1
    j=j-1
    if t[i][j]==0:
        cost=cost+1
return cost-1
```

//here puts the queens in table. But on which criteria?

```
def putOnPosition(t,pi,pj):
n=len(t)
m=len(t[0])
for i in range(0,len(t)):
    for j in range(0,len(t[i])): 
        if pi==i and t[i][j]==0:
            t[i][j]=1
        if pj==j and t[i][j]==0:
            t[i][j]=1
i=pi
j=pj
while i>0 and j>0:
    i=i-1
    j=j-1
    if t[i][j]==0:
        t[i][j]=1
i=pi
j=pj
while i<n-1 and j<m-1:
    i=i+1
    j=j+1
    if t[i][j]==0:
        t[i][j]=1
i=pi
j=pj
while i>0 and j<m-1:
    i=i-1
    j=j+1
    if t[i][j]==0:
        t[i][j]=1
i=pi
j=pj
while i<n-1 and j>0:
    i=i+1
    j=j-1
    if t[i][j]==0:
        t[i][j]=1
t[pi][pj]="X"
return


def getMinCostPosition(t):
min=-1
pi=-1
pj=-1
for i in range (0,len(t)):
    for j in range(0,len(t[i])):
        if t[i][j]==0:
            cost=getPositionCost(t, i, j)
            if min==-1:
                min=cost
                pi=i
                pj=j
            elif cost<min:
                min=cost
                pi=i
                pj=j
return pi,pj,min


def gbfs(m,n):
queens=0
table = [[0 for x in range(n)] for x in range(m)] 
#table=create_table(4,5)
for line in table:
    print(line)

i,j,mi=getMinCostPosition(table)
while i!=-1:
    i,j,mi=getMinCostPosition(table) 
    putOnPosition(table, i, j)
    i,j,mi=getMinCostPosition(table) 
for line in table:
    print(line)
for i in range(0,len(table)):
    if "X" in table[i]:
        queens=queens+1
print("Maximum number of queens :"+ str(queens))
return queens
```

I want to understand the logic behind the code, I tried to take every step on paper but I've lost it. i don't understand what is the criteria such a queen is put on the table? And what cost means?
If I give a 3x3 table the output is:

```
 ['X', 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 'X']
 [1, 1, 1]
```

And it's ok, but if I give 4x4:

```
['X', 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 'X']  
[1, 'X', 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Why the queen wasn't put in the 2nd line, 3rd column?

Comment: This doesn't really look like very good code to be learning from. There's a very basic error in the first function (which I see is not used by the later code, the call is commented out), and the algorithm doesn't really make any sense. I'd throw that code away and find another, better solution.